# widget could not be loaded having Floating action button

Tags: android, android-widget, floating-action-button

When I put a widget on the main screen then instead of showing its respective layout it shows widget having content **Problem loading widget**
and same layout is working fine when we put normal button in it
Widget layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:transitionGroup="true"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
      android:text="Widget" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's only having `FloatingActionButton`

`ap_widget_info.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="146dp"
    android:layout_height="146dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0">
</appwidget-provider>
```

`AppWidgetProviderClass` is

```
public class OpenMapAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OpenMap.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);


            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Doc of App Widgets state that A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the list of layout and `LinearLayout` is one of them and `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton` also a child class of `android.widget.ImageButton` which is also supported by doc then why this problem is occurring

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use custom views in a RemoteView (including extensions of existing view), so you'll have to stick with the basic view types supported.

Answer (score 0):

App widgets say support the following layout classes:`FrameLayout` ,`LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout`,`GridLayout`,and the following widget classes: `AnalogClock`,`Button`,`Chronometer`,`ImageButton`,`ImageView`,`ProgressBar`,`TextView`,`ViewFlipper`,`ListView`,`GridView`,`StackView`,`AdapterViewFlipper`.

it said "Descendants of these classes are not supported." in last line. `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton` is a child ｃlass of `android.widget.ImageButton`. child class of thoes don't support.